# Augment parameter list after partial application in Language-Ext

Tags: c#, functional-programming, language-ext

I'm using [language-ext](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext) in a C# .NET Core project and I'm able to do partial application on an existing function:

```
Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, R> originalFun = /* ... */;

Func<T4, R> partialFun = par(originalFun, paramT1, paramT2, paramT3);
```

Now, I'd like to *augment* parameter list in order to match an existing signature, where additional parameters would just be ignored. In plain language I can write:

```
Func<U1, U2, T4, R> augmentedFun = (_, __, paramT4) => partialFun(paramT4);
```

I wonder if there any "standard" tool available in that library to achieve that, much in the same way as `par` replaces manual lambda expressions. TA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is some existing LanguageExt helper function to allow that style `par` and similar helpers use and there might be a good reason to not add this:

One would probably need a lot of those helper functions to allow having relevant arguments at any position. What about this use case:

`Func<T1, U1, U2, R> augmentedFun = (paramT1, _, __) = someFunction2(paramT1)`

and this

`Func<U1, T2, U2, R> augmentedFun = (_, paramT2, __) = someFunction3(paramT2)`

and this one:

`Func<T1, U1, T3, R> augmentedFun = (paramT1, _, paramT3) = someFunc4(paramT1, paramT3)`

The lambda expression in your working solution makes it very clear what your intent is, i.e. which args to omit.

BTW: Would be great if C# would let us omit dummy variables `_` and `__` here or use wildcard. I found a discussion on this (throwaway variables, discards) [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/8074) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/14794). But wildcard support is limited to tuple deconstruction like `var (_, _) = (3,4);` in C# 7.

If C# would use tuples same way it uses function argument lists many things would be better, especially in LanguageExt context.